# DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern language option

Tags: java

How can I change the language in the MM of `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy")`.
I've tried the Windows language settings but that doesn't seem to have any relevance.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you must specify than two `MM` letters. Two means the month number, not the name. So no language involved until you add more letters.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MMM-uuuu" ) ;
```

Secondly, specify a human language and cultural norms by specifying a `Locale` object.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MMM-uuuu" ).withLocale( Locale.ITALY ) ;
```

Tip: let *java.time* automatically localize for you rather than hard-coding a particular format.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ) ;
Locale locale = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.FULL ).withLocale( locale ) ;
String output ld.format( f ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change language like this:

```java
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.FRENCH);
```

Comment: Thanks for both great answers.